# Space before chapters and contents

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

I am using LaTeX to write my dissertation, and I have realised that on the table of contents and on every chapter page, LaTeX leaves a lot of empty space.

What I mean is that lets say in the page where chapter 1 begins, from the top of the page until the chapter title there is much more vertical space than on any other page. The same goes with chapter 2 etc... and for contents page as well.

Can anybody help me to remove that space?
Is there any mistake in my code or something like that? Is this a default of LaTeX?

the preamble is

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{a4paper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

I've tried the methods below, but none of them work properly.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. The spacing really depends on the document class and mabye related packages.

Comment: I want to add that this default behaviour of `scrreprt` is really strange. Usually you don't want so much whitespace before a chapter, at least if you have a limit of totally available space.

Answer (score 35):

Werner answered the questions for the standard classes. If you use `scrbook` or `scrreprt` (KOMA-script) the space before and after the chapter title is given by `\chapterheadstartvskip` and `\chapterheadendvskip`. These "lengths" are not defined as lengths, but as commands instead. To change the settings you must use `renewcommand`:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{1cm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{2cm}}
```

With KOMA-script version 3.16, a new interface was introduced to change the appearance of sectioning commands, including chapters. You can now do something like this

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,
afterskip=2cm]{chapter}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Incidentally, I also found [a reply by Markus Kohm himself](http://www.komascript.de/node/179) which leads to `\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}`.

Comment: @henry: Of course this is another possibility. \topskip has a length of 11pt.

Answer (score 30):

This is the default behaviour of for `\chapter` (and `\chapter*`) in both [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) document class, so you're doing nothing wrong. This default length is `50pt`.

You could use the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to remove (or modify) the spacing above the chapter headings. Here's a minimal example that will work with either `book` or `report` document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}% Removes space above \chapter head
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}% Removes space above \chapter* head
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter*{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

`\patchcmd` searches for `\vspace*{50\p@}` in both `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` and replaces it with nothing, thereby removing the space. If you want to add a little space, you can insert something different as the replacement text. For example

```
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{20pt}}{}{}%
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{20pt}}{}{}%
```

will insert `20pt` instead of the default `50pt`.

[`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was added to show the frame of the text block and was merely used for illustrative purposes - you can remove this.

---

An alternative to this would be to use the [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). However, in order to modify the `\chapter` spacing (via `\titlespacing{\chapter}...`), you are also required to modify the `\chapter` format (via `\titleformat{\chapter}...`). See the [`titlesec` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! After all these years, your solution keeps being useful for people like me!

Comment: For anyone using the `sectsty` package to change the font of the section headings: The solution with `etoolbox` of this answer has to be inserted *after* `sectsty`.

Answer (score 19):

The default style for LaTeX's book class is quite generous with the whitespace on the page -- there's probably nothing wrong with your code.

One way to change the behavior of headings is to use the [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, which allows you finegrained control over how all the levels of headings are displayed. For example, the following code in the preamble of the document would remove the whitespace above the chapter heading:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
```

In the last line, the four measurements are the left, upper and lower spacing around the heading, respectively. The second one is normally 50pt; it was changed here to 0pt to remove the white space above the chapter heading completely.

Comment: This does nothing in my tex document. Has anything changed?

Comment: This doesn't work. Use `\usepackage{showframe}` and you will see space between the top of the page and the chapter title. Tested in document class `book` and `report`. Bug officialised at https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/53. Workaround: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59389/package-titlesec-adds-extra-space-on-top-of-chapter-despite-commands-to-the-co/59392#59392

Answer (score 10):

With the `report` class the space before a chapter title is 50pt. The easiest method for changing it is to patch the two relevant commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing 

%\pagestyle{plain} % default for report

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{0pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{0pt}{}{}
\makeatother

<rest of the preamble>

\begin{document}

<the document>

\end{document}
```

You can play with the figures: instead of `0pt` you can put any dimension you want.

Note that there's *no* `a4paper` package; to get page parameters suitable for ISO A4 paper you need to specify `a4paper` as an option to `\documentclass`.

Comment: This somehow does not work for me with the book class. I want the "Chapter 1" line to appear right at the top. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @IvanPerez What document class are you using?

Comment: The document class book

Comment: @IvanPerez Change `0pt` to something like `-24pt` (it depends on the main font size, though).

Comment: I changed it to -100pt, and it had no effect. It's like it's not using `\@makechapterhead` at all. I removed every import but this and left only one chapter to obtain a minimal example, and it still won't make a difference. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and installing latex from the default repositories.

Comment: @IvanPerez Maybe you're using something like `titlesec`?

Comment: I tried that too (and separately), but I removed that `usepackage` to find a minimal example, and the issue persists.

Comment: @IvanPerez Sorry, but the information is insufficient and dealing with this in comments is impossible. Add a fresh question with the details.

Comment: Finally after several hours looking everywhere I have found something that works just the way I wanted. For all of you noobs like me out there, make sure to copy all the 5 lines (\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{0pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{0pt}{}{}
\makeatother)