# Title of chapter wanted nearer to the top of the page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Space before chapters and contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39988/space-before-chapters-and-contents)

Is there any way of getting the title of the chapter closer to the top of the page than the default when using `\chapter{blahblah}`?

I have a table I need to put into my appendix, but it is too big to fit on a whole page with the title of the chapter being where it is.

I'm new to LaTeX, so please try and be as simplistic as possible (if there is a solution that it)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please let us know if the linked question solves your problem. If not, please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: Take a look at the `titlesec` package. If you specify more explicitly what you want (with MWE) then we can give more explicit help.