# How to make your chapters' titles a bit up in the page?

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I have these commands for my chapter titles, how can I make it go to the top of page?

```
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bf}{\thechapter}{15pt}{\huge\bf}
```

It's way down the page:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting fragments of code, it's more helpful to create a small self-contained document that shows what you're doing (like the one in my answer). It should begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`.  This way people will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've set the format of `\chapter` using the `titlesec` `\titleformat` command you can set the spacing for the chapters using the `\titlespacing*` command. I've adjusted some of your code  too. Two-letter font commands like `\bf` have been deprecated in LaTeX for decades, and you should not use them. Instead use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}` as appropriate.  Unless the format of the chapter number is different from the rest of the title, there's no need to add formatting to the last argument of the `\titleformat` command.

The `\titlespacing*` command takes four arguments:

```
\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left-margin>}{<space-before>}{<space-after>}
```

The `book` class sets these values to `0pt`, `50pt` and `40pt`. To put the title at the top of the page, we can use a negative value for the space before argument. I've used `-\baselineskip`. If you want the title aligned flush with the top margin, you can use `-1.5\baselineskip` or use the code provided in the comment. If you want some space, but not the default `50pt` then change this value to something that suits your needs.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{15pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{20pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
This is some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Because of a bug (https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/53) there is a little space remaining at the top. Here is a workaround: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59389/package-titlesec-adds-extra-space-on-top-of-chapter-despite-commands-to-the-co/59392#59392. In short: `\usepackage{etoolbox}` an then `\makeatletter\patchcmd{\ttl@mkchap@i}{\vspace*{\@tempskipa}}{}{}{}\makeatother`.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide some more crucial information.

If you are referring to a `\mainmatter` chapter, you may use `\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-Xpt}}` to reduce the skip by inserting a value in `X`.