# How to reduce the gap at the beginning of chapter 1?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{mnnit}
\usepackage{graphicx,times,epsfig,amsmath}
\usepackage[Sonny]{myfancy}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{algorithmwh}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{algorithms}% \Add{} and \Del{} Corrections and \Mark{}

\flushbottom
\include{chapter1}
\flushbotton  

%\appendix
%\chapter{Publications Related to Thesis Work}
%\begin{enumerate}
% \item  Kumar, Prveen., Samaddar, Shefalika Ghosh., Samaddar, Arun B. \& Misra, Arun K., (2010); \textbf{Extending IEEE LTSA e­learning Framework in Secured SOA Environment},
 % The 2nd IEEE International Conference on Education Technology and Computer (ICETC 2010), IEEE Education Society (ISBN: 978-1-4244-6368-8), Shanghai China, June 22-­24, 2010.
%\textbf{(Accepted)}
%\item   Kumar, Prveen., Samaddar, Shefalika Ghosh., Samaddar, Arun B. \& Misra, Arun K.,(2010);\textbf{Extending IEEE LTSA e­learning Framework in Secured SOA Environment},
 % IEEE Transaction on Leatning Technology. \textbf{(Under Peer Review)}
%\end{enumerate}
%\section{References}
\bibliography{research}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

And I also want to reduce the gap between the header and first line.

### Addendum

Just to be clear, I want to reduce the vertical spacing just before of any "Chapter #". This must be defined somewhere in `mnnit.cls`. But, as I'm new to LaTeX, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

[Here is the link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx6lCO-PLMCQRm9BcmNqLV9CeGM&usp=shar%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bing) where I posted the `.tex` file along with the `.cls` file used (possibly some command here needs to be changed).

Comment: And I also want to reduce the gap between the header and first line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do us a favour and register for this site with some name different to user..... Thanks. I added your comment in your question. Could you please reduce your code in order to show only the problematic part! We do not like reading and checking that much code in order to help. What have you tried so far? Where are you having problems? This question does not show a lot of research effort. You could add some explanation of what you are trying. If possible, do not use special documentclasses for your example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to reduce the so much gap at the beginning of chapter 1. Please give me the solution how can I overcome this problem.

Comment: @shelly: Why are you continously editing the title and introducing typos others already corrected for you? ;-)

Comment: @shelly Your example wont compile like it is right now. What are `\flushbotton` and `\flushbottom` doing? Do not know them, but sounds strange especially if you want to reduce some vertical space.

Comment: I am fresher for latex so I download this code from net.I don't know so much command.But you guess the right thing.

Comment: @shelly -- the `\documentclass{mnnit}` isn't on ctan, so your example won't compile.  the "look" of the chapter headings is defined by the document class, so unless we can learn what it does, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I want to reduce the vertical spacing just before the chapter #. This must be defined somewhere in mnnit.cls, but as I'm new to LaTex, I'm not sure. So, please help me out to reduce the vspace at chapter start.This is the link Where I post the tex filehttps://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx6lCO-PLMCQRm9BcmNqLV9CeGM&usp=sharing

Comment: @shelly In another question you were pointed to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39988/space-before-chapters-and-contents as a possible answer. Does this link help at all? While you are are using a non-standard class, the answer Werner gives there seems to be pretty generic so I would expect to work for you. Please let us know, and also consider making your example truley minimal: at present it relies on a file we don't have and seems to contain lots of unrequired stuff.

Comment: Thank to all for answering, My problem is sort out by using these line.                            \makeatletter

\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{10pt}}{}{}%
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{10pt}}{}{}%
%\usepackage{algorithms}% \Add{} and \Del{} Corrections and \Mark{}
\makeatother

Comment: I've voted to close as the problem appears to have been solved in the comments but it is not clear what is being patched, since the class is not available here (and will so presumably disappear from the link at some point). Hence it isn't very clear now and will likely be less clear later. But mostly, it just doesn't seem to be a duplicate yet isn't likely to get an answer and nothing really fitted.