# Reduce the vertical spacing just before the chapter start

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

Please help me out to reduce the vertical space at chapter start.

The link for the .tex, .cls file along with the problem snapshot -

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx6lCO-PLMCQRm9BcmNqLV9CeGM&usp=shar‌​ing

Comment: [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39989)

Comment: Your `main.tex` shows `\usepackage[Sonny]{myfancy}`, which I assume is similar to `\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}`. In that case, [`fncychap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fnctchap) uses `\@makechapterhead` that's built similarly to what one would find in `report` or `book` classes. As such, the solutions presented in [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39988/5764) would work as well.

Comment: Thank you for answering. My problem is sort out. By using these line.                            \makeatletter

\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{10pt}}{}{}%
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{10pt}}{}{}%
%\usepackage{algorithms}% \Add{} and \Del{} Corrections and \Mark{}
\makeatother