# Why does the text begins in the middle

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am making a project. When I made a frontpage and a table of content my text does not begin from the top of the page.

Can someone help me to fix it

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's normal that the chapter heading starts a bit down the page.

Comment: Are you sure because the table of content do the same

Comment: You must know that the table of contents uses `\chapter*`. Hence, as @egreg said, the TOC heading looks like all the other chapter headings.

Comment: How to change it? [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39988)

Answer (score 1):

By default chapter headings start a bit lower on the page which simply is a matter of the typographical design that was set in the LaTeX core. If you want to change it you can have a look at the question [Space before chapters and contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39988/space-before-chapters-and-contents).

Regarding your question about the table of contents: The macro generating it, `\tableofcontents` (assuming that you use the standard classes) is defined like:

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

As you see, after checking for twocolumn-mode it calls the `\chapter(*)` macro and then icludes the `.toc` file via `\@starttoc`. That's why your table of contents starts as low as the first pages of the chapters in your document.