# Decrease spacing before chapter title in mwrep class

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I thought it will be a piece of cake - I started with titlesec, but it ended up with:

> Non standard sectioning command detected(titlesec) Using default spacing and no format.

Then I started digging some other topics, but eventually none of them helped me with this problem. I guess the issue lies within the mwrep class which I'm using, but I'm clueless what hack am I supposed to use. I would greatly appreciate any help. Here's the example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}

\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{100pt}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\chapter{Litwo, Ojczyzno moja!}
Ty jeste\'s jak zdrowie\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39988/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mwrep` class uses a non-standard manner to format their sectioning commands.

To modify the behavior of `\chapter` add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\SetSectionFormatting[breakbefore,wholewidth]{chapter}
        {-20\p@}  %<-------------------- change this value (default is 56)
        {\FormatBlockHeading{\LARGE}}
        {24\p@}
\makeatother
```

As you can note in the comment, adjust the value to your needs.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}

\makeatletter
\SetSectionFormatting[breakbefore,wholewidth]{chapter}
        {-20\p@}  %<-------------------- change this value (default is 56)
        {\FormatBlockHeading{\LARGE}}
        {24\p@}
\makeatother

\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\chapter{Litwo, Ojczyzno moja!}
Ty jeste\'s jak zdrowie\ldots
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I didn't make any effort to try playing with makeatletter... Shame of me :( Anyway, it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mlmmn Happy it helped. Please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) for more info.