# Using titlesec with mwrep class

Tags: titlesec

I use `mwrep` class in my document and try to customize section titles with `titlesec`. It works OK for sections and subsections but it has no effect for chapters.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232794/decrease-spacing-before-chapter-title-in-mwrep-class) I read that "The `mwrep` class uses a non-standard manner to format their sectioning commands".

Would be still possible to use `titlesec` to style the chapter? Or should I forget about it and find another solution?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,polish]{mwrep}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\LARGE\scshape\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {2pc}
  {}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\large\scshape\rmfamily}
  {\thesection.}
  {1em}
  {\MakeLowercase}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\normalsize\itshape\rmfamily}
  {\thesubsection.}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{Lorem}
  \section{Ipsum}
  \subsection*{Dolor}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just don't use the `mwrep` class, if it doesn't suit you.

Comment: @egreg It is a `report` class adjusted according to Polish typographic standards so it _does_ suit me a lot! I just have this one problem.

Comment: Sorry, but `titlesec` is not compatible with the class. There is some documentation of the class in the file `mwcls.dtx` that you should have in your system, but it is written in Polish. You perhaps can understand it and guess what to modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the chapter use

```
\SetSectionFormatting[breakbefore,wholewidth]{chapter}
   {56pt}
   {\FormatBlockHeading{\LARGE\scshape\bfseries}}
   {24pt}
```

For `section` and `subsection` there are also macros so that you do not need the `titlesec` package

Comment: Thanks, I've found that bypass as well. But it seems to have some limitation, e.g. I cannot use `\MakeUppercase` with that macro. Perhaps it has other limitation compared to `titlesec`.

Answer (score 2):

So, I finally read the documentation for `mwrep` (`mwcls`, actually) and found out that `SetSectionFormatting` is more flexible than I thought.

By having access to `\HeadingNumber` and `\HeadingText` you can write for example

```
\SetSectionFormatting[breakbefore,wholewidth]{chapter}
  {56pt}
  {\large\textbf{\ifHeadingNumbered
    \llap{\fbox{\strut\HeadingNumber.}\enspace}\fi
    \HeadingText}
  }
  {24pt}
```

to get framed chapter number hanging on the margin
[image]

or

```
\SetSectionFormatting[breakbefore,wholewidth]{chapter}
  {56pt}
  {\normalfont\large{
    \ifHeadingNumbered\HeadingNumber.\enspace\fi
    \MakeUppercase{\textls[150]{\HeadingText}}
    }\vspace{1em}\hrule
  }
  {24pt}
```

to get the chapter title capitalized with increased letterspacing (`textls` from `microtype` package) and horizontal rule below.

[image]