# Changing space before chapter without titlesec package

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I am sorry if this is a repeated question, I could not find anything similar on the forum search.

How to adjust the space **before** the chapter heading without using `titlesec` package.

I tried this code but no luck:

`\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}`

It says that `\chapterheadstartvskip` is not defined.

Comment: It probably isn't defined. Why would that command be defined? Are you using a package or class that claims it is? A [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) would be helpful.

Comment: That command exists in scrbook or scrreprt from KOMA-Script.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39988/space-before-chapters-and-contents

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39988)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give the documentclass you are using. So I will let loose my guess that it is `book`. Here the default space above is defined by `\vspace*{50\p@}`. This can be patched as in this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext,showframe}   %% just for demo
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{20\p@}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{20\p@}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Adjust `20` in `\vspace*{20\p@}` as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer. The class i am using is `\documentclass{abntex2}` which is based on the `\documentclass{memoir}` class

the fix for the chapter space was to combine the metric `\beforechapskip` with the redefinition of the command `\chapterheadstart` that somehow got lost inside the abntex2 package.

```
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
\setlength\beforechapskip{20mm}
\setlength\afterchapskip{20mm}
```