# Remove space before appendix chapter

Tags: appendices, book-design

I would like to remove the 50pts of vertical space before the chapter when it is an appendix (leaving the default space for normal chapters). Here is a mwe

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book} 

\usepackage{fontspec}                    
\usepackage{polyglossia}             
\usepackage{titlesec}                       
\usepackage{appendix}  

\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal chapter}
\chapter{Normal chapter}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix chapter}
\chapter{Appendix chapter}

\end{document}
```

I tried to comment the space in the book class declaration by adding this in the preamble

```
%remove vspace before chapter
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

but doing so will remove the space for all chapters. Is it possible to add an if-else condition to the code to remove the space only if it is an appendix?

Comment: Don't place it in the preamle, place it just in front of `\appendix` or add the code to the definition of appendix. First seems to be much easier for you right now [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39989)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was possible, I thought the preamble was the only palce to put it. Thank you very much, it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution with the `apptools` and `titlesec` packages:

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{appendix, apptools}
\AtAppendix{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\vspace*{-50pt}\bfseries\huge}{\chaptername~\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal chapter}
\chapter{Normal chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix chapter}
\chapter{Appendix chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution, in my opinion is to remove some space before each appendix, as below:

```
\chapter{\vspace{-5cm}Appendix 1}
```

and etc.

Comment: This leaves 'Appendix A' bellow the title and I can't do anything about that.