# Vertical space above title of chapters

Tags: vertical-alignment, chapters, templates

I have download a thesis template from [this link](https://github.com/saiwal/latexthesis) and I would like to vary the vertical space (as in attached image) above the title of chapters. What modifications should I make in [Thesis.cls](https://github.com/saiwal/latexthesis/blob/master/Thesis.cls) file in order to achieve the desired.

Thanks[image]

Comment: I would stay away from that template. It is outdated and very very bad.

Comment: Also, using GitHub repis of random people is never a good idea. Check the website the template comes from for a new version (it is very easy to modify what you want with the new version), but honestly I would stay away from this as well.

Comment: And by the way, you should never change a class file.

Comment: Johannes_B : could you please suggest a better template to me

Comment: The newer version of the template. Or even better:https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Comment: Is there any news here? Was my answer helpful? Maybe did it even answer your question? If yes, you can hit the checkmark icon.

Comment: hello Johannes, you have suggested a good template but you have not answered this specific question. I would prefer to wait, thanks.

Comment: With the template you are (probably) using right now, the solution is in the link at the very bottom.

Comment: The file you are linking to (noticed the link just now) is hopefully not the file you are really using. You should *not* use it. Not only is it old, is was modified and is no longer the template, so it is unsupported. And pretty much a copyright violation, if somebody would care.

Comment: In other words, what you downloaded is *not* a template. What you are looking for is mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With an up to date [version of the template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis), you have the following default layout. Option `showframe` (of package `geometry` puts the lines on the page as visual help.  The package also controls the page margins.

[image: mdtDefault]

With `\renewcommand{\abovechapterskip}{}` you can control the space, in this case to have no spacing at all.

[image: mdtNoskip]

But honestly, i would use a minimal template instead. In that case, have a look at [Control space above chapter and contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39988/space-before-chapters-and-contents)

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that the linked github repository stripped the license, which is *CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)*. That is basically a violationn of trust.

Taking the template unmodified as it was at that time (v.1.4.3), the already [linked solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50068/37907) works perfectly fine:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{0pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{0pt}{}{}
\makeatother
```

If one is careful about writing a thesis, one does a bit of research and finds the original place of the template, where it is updated and maintained. See [the earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420637/37907).

Better even would be to [use a minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

---

One last word of advice: Stay away from the linked github repository.
Since there is no Readme, and no license, that means you can look at the code, but don't use it. Which is to some extend license infringement.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion may be caused by the previous pages however the abbreviations section actually uses the default template of the page (refer to the chapters themselves). Simply change the top margin on line 78:

```
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\setmarginsrb  { 3.5cm}  % left margin
                    { 2.5cm}  % top margin
                    { 2.5cm}  % right margin
                    { 2.5cm}  % bottom margin
                    {  20pt}  % head height
                    {0.25in}  % head sep
                    {   9pt}  % foot height
                    { 0.3in}  % foot sep
```

Comment: One should never change a class file!

Comment: @Liam, that did not solved my problem, i wanted to change the height of chapter title only