# Reduce spacing between chapter and head of page

Tags: spacing, chapters, templates

I'm a bit frustrated because I am writing my thesis in latex and I used the graduate-thesis template from sharelatex.

I just want to reduce the spacing before a new Chapter that is generated between the top of the space and the "Chapter x" with the \chapter{"example chapter"} command.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, this is the same question as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419755/vertical-space-above-title-of-chapters. Please see the comments to that question. Also have a look at https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md

Answer (score 0):

Since this class is based on the `book` class, one can take a look at that. Then you will realize that `\chapter` uses `\@makechapterhead` which is responsible for this spacing. You can change the original code (from `book.cls`) accordingly in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{0\p@}% This is generating the additional space. default {50\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

A word of caution: This is a well established standard. I wouldn't suggest to do big changes to that. But in the end it's up to you—your gusto and decision.