# Removing chapter titles but not the chapter number

Tags: chapters, titles, naming

Using `\chapter{Title of Chapter X}` I get the chapter number and then under it the tile at the beginning of every chapter:

> Chapter 1
> Title of Chapter 1
> Chapter 2
> Title of Chapter 2
> Chapter 3
> Title of Chapter 3

I want to have the chapters given just by number, with the space where the title would go also deleted:

> Chapter 1
> Chapter 2
> Chapter 3

(And then in the contents page, it should have the chapters listed just by number too.)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Just use `\chapter{}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ?

Comment: As always on this site, you should provide a small but full example such that we have an idea which class are you using and which packages are you using (that are relevant for chapter formatting). Som classes come with features to reformat how chapters look, others don't, thus this information is very important

Comment: Sorry: \documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}. I don't think I'm using a special package for the chapter formatting. If I just use \chapter{} I still get the gap where the chapter title should go.

Answer (score 4):

The gap can be adjusted by `\vspace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{title of Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{}
\vspace{-24pt}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

See [Space before chapters and contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39988/space-before-chapters-and-contents) for more possible solutions.